# Double backup and migration for Iphone

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger

I am about to migrate from a Xiaomi Mi6 to an Iphone 15. I have a regular whatsapp installed on the Mi6. Its backup is configured to Never backup on Google Drive.

However, I do have data in an old backup on Google Drive that I need to retrieve before moving to the Iphone. After retrieving the messages and files from the *old* Google Drive backup, I need to come back to the *current* whatsapp messages so I can migrate to the Iphone using my *current* regular whatsapp.

So I am detailing this workflow to avoid any major headache:

1. Make a copy in my notebook of the local backups for safety in case anything goes wrong. I'd need to backup only the files in this folder:

[image: Whatsapp\Databases folder]

2. Uninstall WhatsApp and reinstall it on the Mi6.
3. Select Restore when prompted, from Google Drive.
4. Retrieve messages and files I need.
5. Rename msgstore.db.crypt14 to whatever other name.
6. Rename msgstore-YYYY-MM-DD.1.db.crypt14 to msgstore.db.crypt14.
7. Uninstall WhatsApp and reinstall it on the Mi6.
   *At this point, all media, including files, documents, audio, images and video will be available as of before this whole process. Please confirm! I will do this first time in the next morning so I don't lose today's messages due to the local backup time at 02:00 AM.*
8. Migrate everything from Mi6 to Iphone using Move to ios.

Please confirm it should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it is useful to anyone, it almost worked. The only issue was that the old backup, in Google Drive, was deleted to inactivity after a few months. But the local backup worked as expected.